# Pointer to array - initialize element

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a class `Pixel` and a class `Image` with a function used to update a pixel line. I want to initialize the pixel line. My problem is to initialize the array. Actually I have this :

```
bool UpdateLine(Pixel line[], int nb)
{
    bool noError = true;
    line = new Pixel[nb];
    for (int r = 0; r < nb; r++)
    {
        line[r] = new Pixel(); // -> line causing troubles

        // do some stuff with my pixel
        [...]
    }
    return noError;
}
```

When I try this I have :

> no viable overloaded '='

How can I initialize each elements for my array ?

Comment: `line` is an array of objects! They are all already constructed. C++ works differently to C# or Java. [A good book or two is a must, I think.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You actually have *two* problems.

The first, regarding your error, is because `new Pixel()` results in a *pointer* to a `Pixel` object. In C++ you don't need `new` to create objects (do you come from a Java or C# background perhaps?). The initial allocation of the array creates the objects for you.

The second problem is that you assign to the pointer variable `line`, but `line` is a *local variable* inside the function. All modification to it will be lost once the function returns, and you will have a memory leak. You need to pass `line` *by reference*.

---

In the future when dealing with collections of a single type of data, I suggest you use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead. You still need to pass the vector by reference though, if you want to add elements to it.

Comment: Or enjoy the beauty/power of modern C++ and just return the vector by value

Comment: My code has been automatically generated from C# by a piece of software, I am not yet very comfortable with the C++. I will use vector instead array. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Just for sure, `bool UpdateLine(std::vector<Pixel>* line, int nb)` will be better ?

Comment: @A.Pissicat I would use `std::vector<Pixel>&` instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
    line[r] = new Pixel(); // -> line causing troubles
```

`line[r]` is a Pixel object, not a pointer, so you can't assign a pointer to it.

Why aren't you using a std::vector?

Comment: I'll use vector instead, this part has been automatically generated from C#, I had not thought of replacing it with a vector

Comment: @A.Pissicat most times when you're looking at dynamically sizing an array in C++, you should be using a std::vector instead.  Create the vector inside your function and return it by value.  No need to pass in an empty one to the function.